# Use python with custom build of openssl

Tags: python, ssl, ld-preload

The python module `ssl` is using the build of `openssl` which is installed system-wide. I have a separate build that I compiled. I tried `LD_PRELOAD=./libcrypto.so python3`, but `ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION` still shows the version of the system build.

How can I tell python to use my custom `openssl`? Is there a way that does not require to recompile python?

I'm on Debian in case that's relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the directory containing the new libraries, it works. So if the libraries are located in the current working directory, this works:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$(pwd):$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" /usr/bin/python3
```